# Convert WPF form code for WPF Xaml for datagrid to get specific row

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have the following code written in WPF forms and it was working perfectly fine. But then I decided to use XAML for better GUI result. This method was attached to the "CellClick" event in WPF Forms. It is basically responsible for getting the selected row and then it queries for it to get data from database. Now in XAML there is not such event called "CellClick". What would be the alternative and how I get the selected row from a datagrid in XAML.

```
     private void employeeInfo_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            empId = Convert.ToInt32(employeeInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Employee ID"].Value.ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE [Employee_id]=@employeeId";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeId", empId);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt);
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                employeeIDTxt.Text = dr["Employee_Id"].ToString();
                firstNameTxt.Text = dr["First_Name"].ToString();
                lastNameTxt.Text = dr["Last_Name"].ToString();
                addressTxt.Text = dr["Address"].ToString();
                aptTxt.Text = dr["Apt"].ToString();
                stateTxt.Text = dr["State"].ToString();
                cityTxt.Text = dr["City"].ToString();
                zipTxt.Text = dr["Zip"].ToString();
                phoneTxt.Text = dr["Phone"].ToString();
                cellTxt.Text = dr["Cell"].ToString();
                emailTxt.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
                hourlyPayTxt.Text = dr["Hourly_Pay"].ToString();
                passwordTxt.Text = dr["Password"].ToString();
                statusTxt.Text = dr["Status"].ToString();

            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException arg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a vlaud Employee" +arg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("WTF happened bro. check it again. Inside the Employee Info method" + ex);
        }
    }
```

I have tried the code below to get the specific columns from the selected row but the problem with this is that this event gets fired twice and on the second time it throws an argumentOutOfBound exception.

```
        private void employeeInfo_CellClick(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("EmployeeInfo method");
        DataRowView dg = (DataRowView)employeeInfo.SelectedItems[0];
        empId = Convert.ToInt32(dg["Employee ID"]);
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use InputBindings

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding GoCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=SelectedItem}"></MouseBinding>
        </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=SelectedItem}" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

VM etc:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TestItem> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TestItem> { new TestItem() { Id = 1, Name = "Foo" }, new TestItem() { Id = 2, Name = "Bar" } };

    public ICommand GoCommand => new DelegateCommand<TestItem>(Go);

    void Go(TestItem selected)
    {
        if (selected != null)
            MessageBox.Show(selected.Name);
    }
}

public class TestItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Note this is just one of a number of ways to do this - you can also create a property in the VM and bind the SelectedItem to it (Mode=TwoWay).

You may want to play around with the editability of the cells/grid.

You can find implementations of DelegateCommand on Google.